# scp when both hosts are remote and use different ports

Tags: ssh, scp, port

I am reposting a slightly edited version of this Ask Ubuntu question [SCP with two different ports](https://askubuntu.com/q/153960/), as [the answer there](https://askubuntu.com/q/153960/#307078) that works with command-line options only (without modifying `ssh_config`) no longer works for me.

How can I use `scp` command to copy files between two remote servers that use different ports from my local PC?

**Setup**

- remote server 1 : IP=67.12.21.133  & **port=6774**
- remote server 2 : IP=67.129.242.40 & **port=6775**

**Problem**

- If I use

  ```
  scp -rp -P 6774 denny@67.12.21.133:/home/denny/testapp1.txt  denny@67.129.242.40:
  ```

  it gives an error:

  ```
  ssh: connect to host 67.12.21.133 port 22: Connection refused
  ```
- If I use

  ```
  scp -rp -P 6774 denny@67.12.21.133:/home/denny/testapp1.txt -P 6775 denny@67.129.242.40:
  ```

  it gives me this error:

  ```
  ssh: connect to host 67.129.242.133 port 6775: Connection refused  
  ssh: connect to host 67.129.242.40 port 6774: Connection refused  
  lost connection
  ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Specify the ports in source and target URLs:

```
scp -3 scp://host1:port1//path/to/file  scp://host2:port2//path/to/file
```