# SCP command from remote to remote keeps asking for password even when I specify the private key file

Tags: scp

I've tried using the `-i` option and also adding the public key to the destination's `authorized_keys` file but nothing seems to be working. Does anybody know what other potential problems there may be? Thank you.

The syntax I'm using is: `scp -i $PATH_TO_PRIVATE_KEY -P port user@host1:file dest@host2:file`.

Comment: [This](https://superuser.com/a/602436/432690).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work... It asks me whether or not I want to permanently add the source's fingerprint but then times out? Maybe this isn't an SCP problem?

Comment: (1) `user@host` and `dest@host` use the same `host`. Why `scp` then? Why not `ssh` and `cp`? Or is `host` resolved differently on your local and on… well, `host`? (2) What is `authorized_hosts`? Do you mean `authorized_keys`?

Comment: Maybe I should have been clearer. 1) The hosts are different. I have a local machine and use two different servers for work. I usually copy the files from A to local, then from local to B but I want to go directly from A to B. 2) Yes, I got confused between `authorized_keys` and `known_hosts`.

Comment: (3) "directly from A to B" (side note: sticking to `host1`,`host2` would be better than introducing A,B; xor the other way around) – So `-3` from the linked answer is not what you want. Read the answer again. You need to be able to `ssh` from your local to A *and from A to B*. Keys have to be set up to support `ssh`-ing from A to B. Are you able to `ssh` this way? (4) Should `-P port` apply to both connections?

Comment: (3 cont.) An idea to set keys up: if you want to authenticate using your local key only, starting a local agent and forwarding it (`scp -A`) may allow the first host to authenticate to the second host with your local key, when not using `-3`. (5) "nothing seems to be working" carries little information. Posting exact `scp -v` commands you used and the output of each respective command would be better.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski Thanks for pointing that out, I'll first set up SSH between A to B. 4) No, I don't believe it should.

Comment: (Ad. 4) Then [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/678412/108618) may be useful.